# Adding default links with Spring HATEOAS

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I have a number of JPA entities, each managed with Spring Rest Data repositories, and I want to overload the POST method on one of them, to make one reset call, and then otherwise be exactly the same.

What I wish to avoid doing is building all my objects and relationships from scratch all the time, I just want to get exactly what spring would give me by default if I had not supplied my own method.

Attempt 1:

Create a controller that looks like:

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class Entity0Controller {
    @Autowired
    Entity0DataRestRepository repo;

    @PostMapping(path="/entity0")
    public Resource<Entity0> createEntity0(Entity0 e)
    {
        e.setName("I have been changed");
        return new Resource<>(repo.save(e));
    }
}
```

Error I get back is:

> Circular view path [entity0]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/entity0] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)

Attempt 2:

Change the POST function to:

```
@PostMapping(path="/entity0")
public @ResponseBody Entity0 createEntity0(Entity0 e)
{
    e.setName("I have been changed");
    return repo.save(e);
}
```

Now I dodge the circular view path error, but I don't get any links at all.

I sense that I am close, and if anyone wants to look at an MCVE/SSCCE (less than 20 lines of code total), the code is here: https://github.com/soandos/spring-rest-override-example

Comment: Do you really need a custom controller? Can't this be done in an event handler? https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#events

Comment: @AlanHay would I be able to get properties of the HTTP call that way? Specifically, I will be wanting the user's (client) certificate information

Comment: Probably. You could try a standard Spring Interceptor which stores the relevant data in a ThreadLocal for use downstream. 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46953039/spring-interceptor-not-working-in-spring-data-rest-urls 2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53399919/1356423